# MDI form in C# Parent And Child

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have 3 forms on my project.

- `form1` is MDI controller
- `form2` and `form3` are MDI children

How do I create `form1` as the parent and `form2` and `form3` as children?

Something like old MFC's MDI interface:

[image]

Imagine `form2` is the parent and has a button. If clicked, it must open `form3` in the parent form (`form1`).  How do I set this up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, make sure Form1's `IsMdiContainer` is set to `true`.

Then instantiate Form1 and Form2, setting Form1 to be Form2's MdiParent:

```
// Form1.IsMdiContainer should be true
Form1 form1 = new Form1();

// This automatically adds form2 into form1's MdiChildren collection
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.MdiParent = form1;
```

In Form2's code, have something like the following to handle the button's click event to instantiate Form3.

```
public class Form2 : Form {
    // Include as data member so we only instantiate one Form3
    Form3 _form3;

    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(_form3 == null) {
            _form3 = new Form3();
            // Set Form3's parent to be Form1
            _form3.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        }
    }
}
```

As a couple notes, this code is really quick and dirty. There are several undesirable things about it like the coupling of Form2 and Form3 (as well as unhelpful class names Form1, Form2, and Form3). Ideally, you'd decouple Form2 and Form3 by raising an event from Form2 that your forms container can hook onto and instantiate Form3. This sample code is meant to give you a direction.

Answer (score 4):

Just tell to the form that its MdiParent is current form.

```
  form2 frm = new form2 ();
    frm.MdiParent = this;
    frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void homeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmHome objfrmHome = frmHome.GetChildInstance();
        objfrmHome.MdiParent = this;
        objfrmHome.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        objfrmHome.Show();
        objfrmHome.BringToFront();
    }
```

Then in the Form you are calling

```
    private static frmHome m_SChildform;
    public static frmHome GetChildInstance()
    {
        if (m_SChildform == null) //if not created yet, Create an instance

            m_SChildform = new frmHome();
        return m_SChildform;  //just created or created earlier.Return it

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
public void mdiChild(Form mdiParent, Form mdiChild)
    {
        foreach (Form frm in mdiParent.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (frm.Name == mdiChild.Name)
            {

                frm.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }

        mdiChild.MdiParent = mdiParent;
        mdiChild.Show();

    }
```