# how to keep all any forms in parent screen c#

Tags: c#, winforms

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCyj8.png)

As you can see in attached screenshot, I open a few form in parent windows form. But if I click another program on my computer, for example Paint, Outlook etc., last opened windows form overlap on new screen. You can see that in second image.

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmWC1.png)

How can I keep all form in parent form borders?

EDIT : I know I should use MDI Parent and I already create main form as a MDI parent form. But last form is not opened from MDI Parent like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076526/mdi-form-in-c-sharp-parent-and-child).

EDIT 2 : Here is the hierarchy;

- Main MDI Form
  -- MDI Child Form
  ---- Form
  ----- Form 2

I want to keep Form 2 in MDI Container. When I use another program, Form 2 is showing center of the screen :)

Comment: The main form is *not* a parent form if you don't explicitly specify this when you open a new form.  Specify a parent form when you open a new form with `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`, eg `Show(this)`. Without a parent, forms can appear outside the main form and can be overlapped by other applications

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Doesn't `ShowDialog(this)` make this the owner, but not the parent? I think he asks for something like MFC's MDI interface - http://www.tenouk.com/visualcplusmfc/visualcplusmfc12mdi_files/image001.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MDI form in C# Parent And Child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076526/mdi-form-in-c-sharp-parent-and-child)